# NullPointerException on Map Object

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I use eclipse and android sdk.I want to pin point a location on map so i use this function when user click on a button:

```
public void pinpointlocation(Context context){

 map = ((SupportMapFragment) ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content))
        .getMap();
 Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
            .title("Hamburg"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(KIEL)
            .title("Kiel")
            .snippet("Kiel is cool")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
}
```

but when i run the program in emulator it crash and get me these error :

```
04-24 06:16:35.327: E/AndroidRuntime(4070): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 06:16:35.327: E/AndroidRuntime(4070):     at com.example.hach.Mhelper.pinpointlocation(Mhelper.java:59)
04-24 06:16:35.327: E/AndroidRuntime(4070):     at com.example.hach.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:90)
```

which line 59 is the first line of the function. Why the map is null?

Comment: Did u check the same in real device

Comment: @SpringBreaker on the first line of the function.

Comment: @Ramkiran yes it crash too.

Comment: Some time if the configuration for google map is wrong then you may get this type of error. so check whether all your setting is as per the doc.

Comment: cross-check the xml and declaration of the variable: map

Comment: @Shombol-shagol read this before deciding to delete. i suggest its a bad idea. http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your **id** in xml is the same as the one you referenced in Activity.

Quoting docs

> A GoogleMap can only be acquired using getMap() when the underlying
>   maps system is loaded and the underlying view in the fragment exists.
>   This class automatically initializes the maps system and the view;
>   however you cannot be guaranteed when it will be ready because this
>   depends on the availability of the Google Play services APK. **If a
>   GoogleMap is not available, getMap() will return null**.

Also check the availability of google play services before initialize map object.

Read **Check for Google Play Services** @

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: the map is showing in the fragment box at the bottom of the layer,it means every thing is Okey.by everything i mean Google Play Services.

Comment: @Shombol-shagol if map is showing then what is the problem?? you should not get NPE unless id of fragment is wrong in xml

Comment: I dont know what is the problem. that is why i asked this question.it dont pinpoint.

Comment: @Shombol-shagol what happens now. The only way you get NPE is bcoz map object is null and the reason is already mentioned in the post. But you say you see the map how is that possible????????

Comment: @Shombol-shagol have you checked for google play services availability before initializing map object??

Comment: Yes it is available because it run the map.

Comment: @Shombol-shagol join the chat @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51348/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-shombol-shagol

Comment: "@Raghunandan" unfortunately i saw your comment one hour later.I am sorry i don't want to be rude.

Comment: @Shombol-shagol you still haven't posted the updated stacktrace and the updated code. So mistake cannot found be found

Comment: "@raghunandan" i highly thank you for your help and your concern,you are the real teacher, i solve the problem,it was silly thing.i wish to remove the question because it was bad asked and miss informed.it was really copy paste problem.my bad.thanks again.

Comment: @Shombol-shagol no need to delete. deleting is very bad coz this is hepful for future visitors. You are not to decide what's bad or wrong. its upto the community

Comment: @Shombol-shagol also deleting a few more can lead to question ban and you can end up not able to ask question in future

Comment: "@raghunandan" i add solution to your answer and accept it.

Comment: @Shombol-shagol well that was already mentioned in comment by other user "cross-check the xml and declaration of the variable: map" But it is not a variable though

Comment: "@raghunandan" i really don't care if stack remove my account because i can always create another, and i don't use my account as my working profile or something, but i like the idea to ask good question and correct it instead of deleting.i asked that miss inform question because i was too tired to think it more :) .

Comment: "@raghunandan" Yes you mention that.I was too tired to listen.